# how to push data into an array with key and value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

i  have this object with arrays

```
$scope.filters = {     
      Sites: [], 
      Regions: [], 
      Devices : [], 
      Variables : [],      
     };
```

i want to push into Variables {'VariableName': 'Total Active Energy'};

i did this

```
     var obj = {};
      obj['VariableName'] = response.data[0].AutoReportVariable;
      $scope.filters.Variables.push(obj);        
      console.log($scope.filters.Variables);
```

but in console I take :

> 0:{VariableName:'Total Active Energy'}
>   how can i push the value to take in console only {VariableName:'Total Active Energy'} without key 0 ?

i want this to have

```
$scope.filters = {     
  Sites: [], 
  Regions: [], 
  Devices : [], 
  Variables : [{VariableName:'Total Active Energy'}]      
 };
```

Comment: that `0` is not key, its the index of array

Comment: You have the format you want! `console.log` shows you indexes too. What is your problem?? Maybe an object??

Comment: console.log($scope.filters.Variables.VariableName); is undefined.

Comment: i have to say console.log($scope.filters.Variables[0].VariableName); is this possible to push this value and console.log($scope.filters.Variables.VariableName); is not undefined?

Answer (score 1):

it's not like that,

```
$scope.filters = {     
    Sites: [], 
    Regions: [], 
    Devices : [], 
    Variables : [],      
};
$scope.filters.Variables.push({
    VariableName: 'Total Active Energy'
});
console.log($scope.filters.Variables);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this code briefly

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.filters = {     
  Sites: [], 
  Regions: [], 
  Devices : [], 
  Variables : [{VariableName:'Total Active Energy'}]      
 };
 
 console.log("showing total araay:");
 console.log($scope.filters.Variables);
 
 console.log("showing item by item");
 $scope.filters.Variables.forEach(function(itm, index) {
  console.log("item " + JSON.stringify(itm) + " is in index " + index)
 });
```

Comment: It is not a solution of angular js

Comment: Is the question related to angularJs? It is something about arrays and objects in javascript! @ProjeshPal

Comment: 1- normally we don't use $scope.variable format in normal JS Unless someone is unawares of AngularJs
2. The post is tagged with angularJs

Comment: So you add `ng-repeat` because of `angularJs`. right? @ProjeshPal

Comment: No. ng-repeat is to demonstrate that after pushing object scope data is working properly in view. And you did not answer  how to push object even in JS. You just run a for each and log static object

Answer (score 0):

You need to push object to the array

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filters = {     
    Sites: [], 
    Regions: [], 
    Devices : [], 
    Variables : []      
   };
   for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
   
   var obj={VariableName:'Total Active Energy'+i};
   $scope.filters.Variables.push(obj);
   }
   angular.forEach($scope.filters.Variables, function(value, key) {
   console.log("item " + JSON.stringify(value) + " is in index " + key)
   });
   
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in filters.Variables">
        VariableName: {{x.VariableName}}
      </li>
  </ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```